# Database items sometimes not showing up in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a simple app written in meteor here: https://gist.github.com/drew-gross/6202629 that is having problems. When the `Template.tab.ordered_drinks` function is called, no Tabs are found (`Tabs.find({}).fetch()` returns an empty array) but only most of the time. Sometimes the Tabs are there. I have checked that they exist in the database.

To reproduce:

1) Run the app. (requires meteor-router)

2) Create a tab on the console: `Tabs.insert({owner:"foo"})`

3) Try to view the page for the tab: `localhost:3000/tabs/:id`

The page will work or not work, seemingly at random. To confirm, you can set a breakpoint on line 9 or 19 of the .js and do `Tabs.find({}).fetch()` and you will sometimes see and sometimes not see the tab.

This kinda seems like a bug in Meteor but I thought I would check first to see if I might be doing something wrong.

Browser: Chrome 28
Meteor version: Release 0.6.4.1
Node version: v0.10.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue might arise if the subscriptions haven't yet got their data.

In meteor the html/js is sent down to the client, it then renders the page. At the same time the client connects to the server via websockets/long polling to retrieve the mongo database.

So sometimes you can render html without yet having anything in your database.

You just need to be careful that you use reactivity to handle when the data arrives and not presume its already there, like here:

```
Template.tab.ordered_drinks = function () {
    return Tabs.findOne(Session.get('tabId')).ordered_drinks;
};
```

if `Tabs.findOne(Session.get('tabId'))` is `null` because there isn't any data on the client (yet) then `.ordered_drinks` wont exist and you would get an error on the chrome console & sometimes see/sometimes not see the tab, depending on whether the database has loaded yet or not.

Try altering the line below to allow `Tabs.findOne(Session.get('tabId'))` to be `null` without throwing an error.

```
Template.tab.ordered_drinks = function () {
    var tab = Tabs.findOne(Session.get('tabId'));
    return tab && tab.ordered_drinks;
};
```

So at this point it is loading. As soon as the data arrives it'll reactively re-render this portion with the tabs.